# What were the Oryo family's paintings meant to depict?

Tags: psycho-pass

Rikako Oryo was the daughter of a genius artist and strictly moral person. As far as I have understood, her father tried to depict the principle that humans can advance their morality by exposing themselves to darker side of humanity. The paintings that he created are gruesome and I do not understand what exactly he wanted to depict through them. His philosophy, and that of Rikako, was difficult for me to grab.

What did the paintings of the Oryos depict exactly? What caused Rikako, a daughter of a strictly moral person, to become a serial killer? Was it the charisma of Makishima that caused her to get manipulated? Further, What did the earlier two plastic models created out of that businessman and an enforcer that Kogami said about, symbolize? These things just add to the gore and seem meaningless. Are they really just meaningless?